# Get endpoint for Terraform with aws_elasticache_replication_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster

I have what I think is a simple Terraform config for AWS ElastiCache with Redis:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "my_replication_group" {
  replication_group_id          = "my-rep-group",
  replication_group_description = "eln00b"

  node_type                     = "cache.m4.large"
  port                          = 6379
  parameter_group_name          = "default.redis5.0.cluster.on"

  snapshot_retention_limit      = 1
  snapshot_window               = "00:00-05:00"

  subnet_group_name             = "${aws_elasticache_subnet_group.my_subnet_group.name}"

  automatic_failover_enabled    = true

  cluster_mode {
    num_node_groups             = 1
    replicas_per_node_group     = 1
  }
}
```

I tried to define the endpoint output using:

```
output "my_cache" {
  value = "${aws_elasticache_replication_group.my_replication_group.primary_endpoint_address}"
}
```

When I run an apply through terragrunt I get:

> Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> module.mod.output.my_cache: Resource 'aws_elasticache_replication_group.my_replication_group' does not have attribute 'primary_endpoint_address' for variable 'aws_elasticache_replication_group.my_replication_group.primary_endpoint_address'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Documentation here says it should be available:  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/elasticache_replication_group.html

Comment: Weird, is this issue applicable at all? https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elasticache-redis/issues/16

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `primary_endpoint_address` attribute is only available for non cluster-mode Redis replication groups as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_replication_group.html#primary_endpoint_address):

> primary_endpoint_address - (Redis only) The address of the endpoint for the primary node in the replication group, if the cluster mode is disabled.

When using cluster mode you should use [`configuration_endpoint_address`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_replication_group.html#configuration_endpoint_address) instead to connect to the Redis cluster.

Comment: I *COMPLETELY* overlooked the "if cluster mode is disabled" part.  :duh: